# Need to rewrite function for date display

Tags: php, datetime

I have the following function that I wrote couple of years ago. It takes a datetime from my db and displays it in a better formatted way.

```
function formatTime($dateTime){
// show time only if posted today
if (date('Ymd') == date('Ymd', strtotime($dateTime))) {
    $dt = date('g:i a', strtotime($dateTime));
} else {
    // if not the same year show YEAR 
    if (date('Y') == date('Y', strtotime($dateTime))) {
        $dt = date('M j', strtotime($dateTime));
    } else {
        $dt = date('M j, Y', strtotime($dateTime));
    }
}

return $dt;
}
```

I use server time, which is CST for me. Yesterday I had a user from Australia pointing out that for him it did not make any since since he way on an entirely different time zone, actually a day ahead (when compared to my output at certain time :).

I decided to rewrite my function to say something like:

- if under a minute > seconds ago
- if under an hour > # minutes ago
- between 1 -2 hrs > over an hour ago
- 2 - 24 hrs > day ago
- 2 - 7 days > # days ago
- 7 days - month > # weeks ago
- 1 - 2 months > over a month
- after that I can just show a date

Are there any functions that you are perhaps aware of doing this, if not how would I modify this one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function formatTime ($dateTime) {

  // A Unix timestamp will definitely be required
  $dateTimeInt = strtotime($dateTime);

  // First we need to get the number of seconds ago this was
  $secondsAgo = time() - $dateTimeInt;

  // Now we decide what to do with it
  switch (TRUE) {

    case $secondsAgo < 60: // Less than a minute
      return "$secondsAgo seconds ago";

    case $secondsAgo < 3600: // Less than an hour
      return floor($secondsAgo / 60)." minutes ago";

    case $secondsAgo < 7200: // Less than 2 hours
      return "over an hour ago";

    case $secondsAgo < 86400: // Less than 1 day
      return "1 day ago"; // This makes no sense, but it is what you have asked for...

    case $secondsAgo < (86400 * 7): // Less than 1 week
      return floor($secondsAgo / 86400)." days ago";

    case $secondsAgo < (86400 * 28): // Less than 1 month - for the sake of argument let's call a month 28 days
      return floor($secondsAgo / (86400 * 7))." weeks ago";

    case $secondsAgo < (86400 * 56): // Less than 2 months
      return "over a month ago";

    default:
      return date('M j, Y', $dateTimeInt);

  }

}
```

This is by no means flawless, especially since one of your requirements doesn't make sense (see comments) but hopefully it should give you a push in the right direction, and illustrate how you can use `switch` to allow you to easily add and remove items/options from the behaviour.

Comment: Oh, this is great! Yep, 1 day ago makes no sense. I guess I can use hours until 24 > yesterday > 48 hrs :)